# Supervisor node .js "Program node app exited with code 0" error

Tags: node.js, express, node-supervisor

When I install an express scaffold app

```
express
```

Then run the npm install

```
npm install
```

and then run supervisor

```
supervisor app
```

I get

```
Starting child process with 'node app'
Program node app exited with code 0
```

**The app.js file is a basic default express instance.**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('static-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(favicon());
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

/// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

/// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
    });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
    });
});


module.exports = app;
```

Comment: `code 0` is not an error.  It indicates the program finished successfully or that `process.exit()` was called without an argument.  You'll need to post the code for `app.js` to get more help.  This isn't enough to do more.

Comment: You might just need to run `supervisor app.js`, looks like you may have forgotten the file ext?

Comment: @Matt Bakaitis I added the app.js file. Its nothing but a basic Express.js instance.

Comment: There is no app.listen in there. The server never actually serves.

Comment: The `module.exports` at the end suggests that this is being called by something else.  Is this part of a framework or a tutorial?  I'm finding other identical code on other StackOverflow questions but I can't find the original source.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The app that the generator creates calls `./bin/www` that includes `app.js` and then starts listening for traffic.

`app.js` **does not do this itself**.

I think this is important to understand.

`app.listen` is **not** being called in `app.js` but is called in `./bin/www`...and this is why you get the `exit 0` result.  When you call `app.js` and not `./bin/www` it runs through the file but because is no command to listen for traffic, the program ends normally...i.e. without having done anything.

That said, you have two options..

**Option 1**

If you have a `./bin/www` file, you could run `supervisor ./bin/www` to get things started.

**Option 2**

If you don't have the `./bin/www` file for whatever reason, you can edit your app file to look like this.

In your app listing, replace

```
module.exports = app;
```

with this

```
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  debug('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
});
```

**Important Note**

While that edit will start the app listening and you won't get an `exit 0` any more, I cannot guarantee that the app won't crash with some other error if other files and directories are missing.  For example, if the `routes` directory isn't present, then the declarations requiring `routes/index` and `routes/users` will fail and other bad things will happen.

Comment: I was using a previous version of node/express and just updated tonight and I am not use to the newer command structure. I didn't use npm start because it doesn't update as you write code , that's why I am trying to use supervisor. Using the command "start supervisor app" works on an older app I made but it doesn't with the code in this post.

Comment: updated my answer.  if you aren't clear about why `supervisor app` is returning an `exit 0` or why calling `supervisor ./bin/www` is an alternative, check out some express.js tutorials and visit the project github page.  the github page has many good example projects that can be really helpful when getting started.

Comment: Why does clicking on the www file run node?

Comment: Clicking on the file launching a program (not just node) depends upon your system setup. It's not a universal behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Default way to run your app, when you use **express-generator**, is to paste

`DEBUG={appName}:* npm start`

`{appName}` - is probably your folder name (like for me), anyway, you can find it in your **package.json -> "name"**;

Answer (score -2):

Thanks for the best answer, finally this works for me:

```
"main": "./bin/www",
"scripts": {
   "start": "node ./bin/www"
}
```