# "nmp start" is not doing anything, what should I do?

Tags: node.js, powershell, cmd, node-modules

I'm currently running a node project where I'm using port 3000 for my localhost and it seems that at the time that I'm running "npm start" it doesn't do anything.

I'm currently using windows, and I ran the following command to kill any activity under this port:

```
 npx kill-port 3000
```

This is what it does after I run "npm start":

```
PS C:\Users\alanharo\Desktop\nodejs_mongo_docker> npm start

> nodejs-mongo-docker@0.0.0 start C:\Users\alanharo\Desktop\nodejs_mongo_docker   
> node ./bin/www
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "nodejs-mongo-docker",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.4",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "express": "~4.16.1",
    "http-errors": "~1.6.3",
    "jade": "~1.11.0",
    "morgan": "~1.9.1"
  }
}
```

Does anyone knows any other solution to this problem?

Comment: What does the `scripts` section in your `package.json` look like? I assume `"start": "node ./bin/www"`. What's `./bin/www`?

Comment: what does this have to do with `powershell`?

Comment: This was setup by itself as soon as I ran npx express-generator

Comment: as Kelvin mentioned, show us the `package.json` file

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32772292/starting-express-js-using-app-js-or-npm-start. You might not have set your express server to `app.listen(3000)`

Comment: try adding a "main" property in your package.json:
`"main": "index.js",` and call your npm start like this: `"start":  "node index.js"`
I can't say that this will work as there is not a lot to go on.